# core.js:9110 ERROR TypeError: $(...).flowchart is not a function

Tags: jquery, angular, flowchart

I am working on an Angular 8 project. In that project I am trying to embed `flowchart` jQuery library into my application.

But when I run my project with `ng serve` it builds successfully but in the browser developer console I see these errors:

```
zone-evergreen.js:172 Uncaught TypeError: $.widget is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (jquery.flowchart.js:4)
    at e (jquery.min.js:2)
    at t (jquery.min.js:2)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:168)
    at invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:465)
    at ZoneTask.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:454)
    at timer (zone-evergreen.js:2650)
client:52 [WDS] Live Reloading enabled.
core.js:9110 ERROR TypeError: $(...).flowchart is not a function
    at flow.component.ts:80
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:34182)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:390)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:168)
    at invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:465)
    at ZoneTask.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:454)
    at timer (zone-evergreen.js:2650)
```

I searched for them and tried to installing related modules and adding following lines in my `angular.json` file of the project:

```
    "scripts": [
     "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
     "./node_modules/jquery.panzoom/dist/jquery.panzoom.min.js",
     "./node_modules/jquery.flowchart/jquery.flowchart.js"

    ]
```

But seems it doesn't work and I still have above errors. I could solve the same error with `panzoom` by this way but it doesn't work for `widget` and `flowchart`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing one js file. I had the same issue in my angular project so in my project i added the following js files.

`jquery-ui.min.js
jquery.panzoom.min.js
jquery.mousewheel.min.js
jquery.flowchart.min.js`

I hope this will help you.